# Computation of an integral

Tags: integration, probability-distributions

While computing densities for some distributions, I stumbled on the following family of parametrized integrals:

$$ p (x) 
:= \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} \int_{\mathbb{R}_+} e^{-\frac{x^2}{2 y^2} - y^2} \ d y.$$

They are obtained by playing around with normal distributions and exponential distributions. Using Wolfram Alpha, the following conjecture seems to hold:

$$ p (x) 
= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} e^{- \sqrt{2} x}.$$

However, I have no idea about how I should prove this equality. I don't think a residue computation may work, because the singularities are essential, but my complex analysis classes are a bit far away, and perhaps there is some nifty trick to solve this problem...

Thank you very much.

Comment: Look at answers of this [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/496088/59379) for some ways to compute the integral.

Comment: @ achille hui : thank you. Well, I think this question is closed. If only there were a simple way to search for similar integrals...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that

$$y^2+\frac{x^2}{2 y^2} = \left ( y + \frac{x}{\sqrt{2} y}\right)^2-\sqrt{2} x$$

Comment: I tried this. It did not help me. In addition, you create a bunch of new terms which cancel later, so I don't think it is the best way to proceed.

Comment: I think the correct expression to use is $$y^2+\frac{x^2}{2 y^2} = \left ( y - \frac{x}{\sqrt{2} y}\right)^2+\sqrt{2} x$$.

Comment: @D.Thomine: see the first solution in that link.  Sorry I did not provide more details, but I had to work on something else.

Comment: @achillehui: either way should work, but you are right, that sub is better.