# Definite integral - closed form: $\int_{0}^{\infty}\cos\left(x^{4} + 1 \over x^{2}\right)\,{\rm d}x$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, closed-form

I'm struggling with this definite integral:

$$ 
\int_{0}^{\infty}\cos\left(x^{4} + 1 \over x^{2}\right)\,{\rm d}x.
$$

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The numerical value seems to be around $-.83$. It most definitely converges since your integral is highly oscillatory. I would like to see if anyone can get a closed form expression for this though.

Comment: The closed form expression is $\int_0^{\infty } \cos \left(\frac{x^4+a^2}{x^2}\right) \, dx = \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} \left(\cos \left(2 a\right)-\sin \left(2 a \right)\right) $, for a > 0. I will try to show it.

Answer (score 19):

$$
I=\int_{0}^{\infty}\cos\left(x^{2} + \frac{1}{x^{2}}\right)\,{\rm d}x
=\int_{0}^{1}\cos\left(x^{2} + \frac{1}{x^{2}}\right)\,{\rm d}x
+\int_{1}^{\infty}\cos\left(x^{2}+\frac{1}{x^{2}}\right)\,{\rm d}x
$$

Substituting $x=1/t$ on the second integral and adding up yields
\begin{align}
&\int_{0}^{1}
\left(1 + \frac{1}{t^{2}}\right)\cos\left(t^{2} + \frac{1}{t^{2}}\right)\,{\rm d}t
=\int_{0}^{1}\cos\left(\left[t-\frac{1}{t}\right]^{2}+2\right)
\,{\rm d}\left(t-\frac{1}{t}\right)
\\[3mm]&=\int_{-\infty}^{0}\cos\left(u^{2}+2\right)\,{\rm d}u
=\int_{0}^{\infty}\cos\left(u^{2} + 2\right)\,{\rm d}u
\\[3mm]&=\cos\left(2\right)
\int_{0}^{\infty}\cos\left(u^{2}\right)\,{\rm d}u
-\sin\left(2\right)\int_{0}^{\infty}\sin\left(u^{2}\right)\,{\rm d}u
\end{align}

Feel free to look up the Fresnel integrals, i.e
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\cos\left(u^{2}\right)\,{\rm d}u
=\int_{0}^{\infty}\sin\left(u^{2}\right)\,{\rm d}u
=\frac{\sqrt{\,\pi\,}\,}{2\,\sqrt{\,2\,}\,}
$$

Adding up we finally arrive at
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\cos\left(x^{2} + \frac{1}{x^{2}}\right)\,{\rm d}x
=\left[\cos\left(2\right) - \sin\left(2\right)\right]\,
\frac{\sqrt{\,\pi\,}}{2\,\sqrt{\,2\,}\,}$$

Comment: Fast and very nice!

Comment: That is not what Mathematica is getting. So maybe you should check.

Comment: It's the same as Mathematica told me, so I think it's correct.

Comment: Sorry, it is okay now.

Comment: +1. It is a nice answer and it is pretty short. I hope you don't mind for my edition.

Answer (score 8):

Rewrite:
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}\cos\left(x^{4} + 1 \over x^{2}\right)\,dx=\int_{0}^{\infty}\cos\left(x^{2} + \frac1{x^2}\right)\,dx=\Re\left[\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{\Large-i\left(x^{2} + \frac1{x^2}\right)}\,dx\right].\tag1
$$
Consider my answer that I posted on Math SE
[$$
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^\infty \exp\left(-a\left(x^2+\frac{b}{ax^2}\right)\right)\,dx
&=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}e^{\large-2\sqrt{ab}}.
\end{align}
$$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/790255/123277)
Taking $a=i$ and $b=i$, where $i=\sqrt{-1}$, then $(1)$ turns out to be
$$
\begin{align}
\Re\left[\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{\Large-i\left(x^{2} + \frac1{x^2}\right)}\,dx\right]
&=\frac{1}{2}\Re\left[\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{i}}e^{\large-2\sqrt{i\cdot i}}\right]\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\Re\left[\sqrt{\pi}\cdot i^{-\large\frac12} \cdot\ e^{\large-2i}\right],\tag2
\end{align}
$$
where
$$
i^{-\large\frac12}=\left(\cos\left(\frac\pi2\right)+i\sin\left(\frac\pi2\right)\right)^{-\large\frac12}=e^{\Large-\frac\pi4i}=\cos\left(\frac\pi4\right)-i\sin\left(\frac\pi4\right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}-\frac{i}{\sqrt2}
$$
and
$$
e^{\large-2i}=\cos2-i\sin2.
$$
Taking the real part of $(2)$, we obtain
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}\cos\left(x^{4} + 1 \over x^{2}\right)\,dx=\color{blue}{\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}(\cos2-\sin2)}.
$$

Comment: The computations in the other answer apply to $a$ and $b$ positive real numbers. Does the result apply to $a$ and $b$ complex? Certainly not without some more work, as witnessed by the awkward treatment of $\sqrt{i}$ in the answer here (one might recall at this point that there is NO square root function defined on the complex plane)...

Comment: @Did I guess it's also work for complex numbers since use the similar technique to answer a few of integration questions here. I know the fact that: "there is no square root function defined on the complex plane", but I often see this treatment of imaginary number to solve many math questions (I forgot where) like I used in this answer. It's just like the math formula that is considering $0^0=1$, although it looks awkward but it works.

Comment: If your point is that you or other users apply without precaution some identities a priori valid in the real domain to some complex values of the parameters to answer some questions on MSE (and that these answers may even garner upvotes and/or be accepted), then yes, I am aware of this unfortunate situation and I maintain that no valid proof can emerge from such moves without further justifications. In the present answer, there are none.

Comment: @Did Well, only this technique that I know to answer this question but the technique on another answer. I'm not a mathematician so I couldn't give you a rigorous proof about the treatment of square root of complex numbers. You might say that I use 'the identity' without precaution & I admit that.

Comment: @RandomVariable Thank you for your comment, but why is the angle $\dfrac\pi4$? Sorry for the stupid question, but I'm not familiar with the contour/ complex integral.

Comment: The comment I left was incorrect.  It would lead to an evaluation of $\int_{0}^{\infty} \cos \left(x^{2}- \frac{1}{x^{2}} \right) \ dx$, not $\int_{0}^{\infty} \cos \left(x^{2}+\frac{1}{x^{2}} \right) \ dx$.

Answer (score 6):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{\int_{0}^{\infty}\cos\pars{x^{4} + 1 \over x^{2}}\,\dd x:\ {\large ?}}$

> \begin{align}
> &\color{#00f}{\large\int_{0}^{\infty}\cos\pars{x^{4} + 1 \over x^{2}}\,\dd x}=\
> \overbrace{\int_{0}^{\infty}\cos\pars{x^{2} + {1 \over x^{2}}}\,\dd x}
> ^{\ds{\mbox{Set}\ x \equiv \expo{\theta}}}\
> \\[3mm]&=\ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\cos\pars{2\cosh\pars{2\theta}}\,\expo{\theta}\,\dd\theta
> =\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\cos\pars{2\cosh\pars{2\theta}}\,
> \bracks{\cosh\pars{\theta} + \sinh\pars{\theta}}\,\dd\theta
> \\[3mm]&=2\int_{0}^{\infty}\cos\pars{2\cosh\pars{2\theta}}\,\cosh\pars{\theta}
> \,\dd\theta
> \\[3mm]&=2\ \overbrace{%
> \int_{0}^{\infty}\cos\pars{2\bracks{2\sinh^{2}\pars{\theta} + 1}}\,
> \cosh\pars{\theta}\,\dd\theta}^{\ds{\mbox{Set}\ t \equiv \sinh\pars{\theta}}}
> =2\int_{0}^{\infty}\cos\pars{4t^{2} + 2}\,\dd t
> \\[3mm]&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\cos\pars{t^{2} + 2}\,\dd t
> =\cos\pars{2}\int_{0}^{\infty}\cos\pars{t^{2}}\,\dd t
> -\sin\pars{2}\int_{0}^{\infty}\sin\pars{t^{2}}\,\dd t
> \\[3mm]&=\cos\pars{2}\lim_{\xi \to \infty}{\rm C}\pars{\xi}
> -\sin\pars{2}\lim_{\xi \to \infty}{\rm S}\pars{\xi}
> \end{align}
>   where $\ds{{\rm C}\pars{\xi}}$ and $\ds{{\rm S}\pars{\xi}}$ are the
>   [Fresnel Integrals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral) and the above limits are equal to $\ds{\root{\pi \over 8}}$.

\begin{align}
&\color{#00f}{\large\int_{0}^{\infty}\cos\pars{x^{4} + 1 \over x^{2}}\,\dd x}=
\color{#00f}{\large\bracks{\cos\pars{2} - \sin\pars{2}}\root{\pi \over 8}}
\approx -0.8306
\end{align}

Comment: Very creative answer. +1

Comment: @RandomVariable Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Note

\begin{align} 
\int_{0}^{\infty}\cos\left(x^{4} + 1 \over x^{2}\right)\,{d}x
&= \frac12 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\cos\left((x-\frac1x)^2+2\right)\>dx= \frac12 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\cos\left(x^2+2\right)\>dx\\
&= \cos2\int_{0}^{\infty}\cos x^2\>dx - \sin2\int_{0}^{\infty}\sin x^2\>dx\\
&
= \frac{\sqrt\pi}2\cos(2+\frac\pi4)
\end{align}
where
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f\left(x-\frac1x\right)dx= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)dx, \>\>\>
 \int_{0}^{\infty}\cos x^2dx = \int_{0}^{\infty}\sin x^2dx = \frac{\sqrt\pi}{2\sqrt2} $$
are used.