# Uniform convergence

Tags: real-analysis, integration, uniform-convergence

Does the given integral: $$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{2x}{t^2}\space e^{-\left(t^2+\frac{x^2}{t^2} \right)} dt $$ Converge uniformly for x $\in \left]0, +\infty\right[$ ?

By bounding the integral I was able to show that the integral does converge uniformly for $x\in \left]a, b\right[$, where $a,b>0$. But is that true for the whole interval?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We assume $x>0$. By the change of variable,
$$
u=\frac xt, \quad du= \frac {x}{t^2}\:dt,
$$ one gets

> $$
> \begin{align}
> \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{2x}{t^2}\space e^{\large-\left(t^2+\frac{x^2}{t^2} \right)} dt& = 2\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{\large -\left(u^2+\frac{x^2}{u^2} \right)} du
> \\\\&=2e^{-2x}\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{\large -\left(u-\frac{x}{u}\right)^2} du
> \\\\&=\sqrt{\pi}\:e^{-2x}
> \end{align}
> $$

where we have used this related [result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/496088/how-to-evaluate-int-0-infty-exp-ax2-frac-bx2-dx-for-a-b0/496101#496101).