# Integral of exponential with rational argument

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Is there any way to solve the following integral?

$$\int_0^\infty \exp\Bigl(-\frac{(y^2 - x^2)^2}{x^2}\Bigr) \mathrm{d}x$$

Assume $y>0$.

Comment: Can you please post your attempt as well?

Comment: This integral is equal to $\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}2$ for all $y\in\mathbb{R}$

Comment: This is the prettiest form I got from original problem using substitutions. Then I tried several methods I know.
The integrand does not fit any common function with simple integral transform (Laplace, Fourier) that would allow to solve it using properties of the transform.

Comment: I attempted to use complex analysis - the integrand has a removable singularity at zero only, $\lim_0 \exp(−\frac{(y^2−x^2)^2}{x^2})\mathrm{d}x=0$. Also $\lim_\infty \exp(−\frac{(y^2−x^2)^2}{x^2})\mathrm{d}x=0$. I suggested a few contours to integrate along including the interval $\mathbb{R}^+$. Resulted to integrals that were useless or that I was not able to solve.

Comment: @PeterForeman That's what WolframAlpha told me. I'm wondering how to get it.

Comment: See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/496088/515527 and note that: $$\frac{(y^2-x^2)^2}{x^2}=\left(\frac{y^2-x^2}{x}\right)^2=\left(\frac{y^2}{x}-x\right)^2$$

Comment: @Zacky Thanks, got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the aproach of [How to evaluate $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\exp(-ax^2-\frac b{x^2})\,dx$ for $a,b>0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/496088/how-to-evaluate-int-0-infty-exp-ax2-frac-bx2-dx-for-a-b0) I got

$$\begin{align}I=&\int_0^\infty \exp\bigl(-\frac{(y^2-x^2)^2}{x^2}\bigr)\mathrm{d}x\\ =& \begin{Vmatrix}t =\frac{x}{y}\end{Vmatrix}=y\int_0^\infty \exp\bigl(-(t-t^{-1})^2y^2\bigr)\mathrm{d}t
= y\biggl(\int_0^1+\int_1^\infty\biggr) \exp\bigl(-(t-t^{-1})^2y^2\bigr)\mathrm{d}t\\
=&\begin{Vmatrix}s=\frac{1}{t}\text{ in first integral}\end{Vmatrix}
=\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{s^2}\exp\bigl(-(s-s^{-1})^2y^2\bigr)\mathrm{d}s+\int_1^\infty \exp\bigl(-(t-t^{-1})^2y^2\bigr)\mathrm{d}x\\
=&\int_1^\infty (1+t^{-2})\exp\bigl(-(t-t^{-1})^2y^2\bigr)\mathrm{d}x
=\begin{Vmatrix}z=t-\frac{1}{t}\end{Vmatrix}=y\int_0^\infty \exp(-z^2y^2)\mathrm{d}z\\
=&y\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{y^2}}=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}
\end{align}$$

Thanks again, @Zacky.