# If $X|\Sigma^{2}=u\sim N(0,u)$ with $\Sigma^{2}\sim exp(1)$ Find the density of X.

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, conditional-probability

I have problems when I get the integral $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-(\frac{x^{2}}{2u}+u)}}{\sqrt{u2\pi}} du$$ what should I do? Or this result is wrong?

Comment: Your integral diverges: the integrand gets large as $u \to \infty$.  Perhaps that should be $-u$ in the exponent?

Comment: @RobertIsrael Sorry I forgot to write the parenthesis. But I don't know if my result is right or wrong because I can't solve that integral...

Comment: If the conditional distribution of $X$ is **standard normal** when given $\Sigma^2=u$, then $X$ is *independent* from $\Sigma^2$.  Did you instead mean $X\mid\Sigma^2{=}u\sim\mathcal {N}(0,u)$ ?

Comment: @GrahamKemp the exercise says that is a Standard normal. I tried to complete another normal distribution to get rid of the integral but I can't do that. If the conditional distribution is a standard normal then both variables are independent? I haven't seen that result yet

Comment: If $X\mid Y=y$ has a distribution whose parameters *do not depend on* $y$, then $X$ and $Y$ are independent.  If the exercise does indeed say $X\mid\Sigma^2{=}u\sim\mathcal N(0,1)$, then: $$f_{X\mid\Sigma^2}(x\mid u)=\dfrac{\mathrm e^{-x^2/2}}{\surd(2\pi)}$$

Comment: @GrahamKemp Sorry, I wrote that wrong. You were right. But I worked with $N\sim(0,u)$ and got that result. I'm stuck on that point

Comment: Well, then it looks correct, but I cannot see that integrating in terms of standard functions...

Comment: Your integral is correct. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/496088) for how to evaluate it (or to avoid evaluating it and find the characteristic function instead). You will get the Laplace distribution.