# Show that $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{-(\frac{a}{x^2}+x^2 )}dx=\sqrt{\pi}e^{-2\sqrt{a} }, \forall a>0$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Show that $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{-(\frac{a}{x^2}+x^2 )}dx=\sqrt{\pi}e^{-2\sqrt{a} }, \forall a>0$.

I know this can be formulated in terms of conditional characteristic function of Cauchy distribution. But that's why I'm here to ask how this integral is computed in the first place (possibly using some complex analysis tools? I'm interested to know!). I tried the standard trick:
$$\begin{aligned}\left(\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{-(\frac{a}{x^2}+x^2 )}dx\right)^2=&\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{-\left(\frac{a}{x^2}+\frac{a}{y^2}+x^2+y^2  \right)}dxdy\\=&\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{-\left(\frac{a(x^2+y^2)}{x^2y^2}+x^2+y^2  \right)}dxdy\\=&\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{+\infty} e^{-\left(\frac{4a}{\sin^2(2\theta)}+r^2  \right)} rdr d\theta \\=&\int_{0}^{+\infty} e^{-r^2} rdr \int_{0}^{2\pi} e^{-\frac{4a}{ (\sin^2(2\theta))}  }d\theta\\=&\int_{0}^{\pi} e^{-\frac{4a}{ (\sin^2(\theta))}  }d\theta \end{aligned}$$

How should I continue from here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to evaluate $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\exp(-ax^2-\frac b{x^2})\,dx$ for $a,b>0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/496088/how-to-evaluate-int-0-infty-exp-ax2-frac-bx2-dx-for-a-b0)

Comment: Use Cauchy-Schlömilch Transformation.

Comment: A tool you can use is [Glasser's Master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glasser%27s_master_theorem), ( Cauchy-Schlömilch Transformation (change variable to $x - \frac{1}{x}$ is a special case of this).