# Fourier Transform of $\frac{1}{t^2 + a}$ via an Integral Representation

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, fourier-transform

So I want to solve the following integral:

$$ I(w) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-j \omega t}}{t^2 + a} dt  $$

where $a \in \mathbb{R}_{++}$. This is just the Fourier transform of $\frac{1}{t^2 + a}$, which, if we consult practically any transform table, or just utilizie a simple half circle contour, we know is:

$$ I(w) = \frac{e^{-\sqrt{a} |w|}}{\sqrt{a}} $$

However, I want to do it a different way using the integral representation for $\frac{1}{t^2 + a}$. Namely:

$$ I(w) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-u(t^2 + a)} e^{-j \omega t} du dt  $$

Switching the integrals gives us:

$$ I(w) = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-ua - \frac{w}{4u}}  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  e^{-u(t + j \frac{w}{2u})} dt du  $$

The inner integral is just a Gaussian integral, so we end up with:

$$ I(w) = \sqrt{\pi} \int_{0}^{\infty} u^{-\frac{1}{2}} e^{-ua - \frac{w^2}{4u}}   du $$

This is where I get stuck. Not only am I having trouble solving the integral, but Mathematica gives me a weird answer when I evaluate this inner integral to give finally give me:

$$ I_{Mathematica}(w) = \pi \frac{e^{-
\sqrt{a} |w|}}{\sqrt{a}} $$

---

**Questions:**

1. How can I solve $I(w) = \sqrt{\pi} \int_{0}^{\infty} u^{-\frac{1}{2}} e^{-ua - \frac{w^2}{4u}}   du $?
2. Where does the extra $\pi$ come from in Mathematica's answer?

Thanks!

Comment: Let me use $a^2$ where you use $a$. Let $x=\sqrt{u}$, and then notice that $x^2+w^2/4a^2x^2=\left(x-w/2ax\right)^2+w/a$. Double the range of integration to the whole real in exchange for a factor of $1/2$, and apply Glasser's Master Theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glasser%27s_master_theorem.

Comment: See [How to evaluate $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\exp(-ax^2-\frac b{x^2})\,dx$ for $a,b>0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/496088).

Comment: @Zachary That works even when the \frac{1}{x} is still in the integrand? I've never heard of this Master Theorem -- very cool, thanks for the link!

Comment: There isn't a factor of $1/x$ after the substitution because $dx=\frac{du}{2\sqrt{u}}$. This is why this approach is perfect for this integral.

Comment: @Zachary Duh. Okay I'm a dummy. I haven't got out my pencil and paper yet. Thanks.

Comment: @Zachary Now I'm not sure how the $\frac{w}{2a}$ piece fits in with Glasser's Theorem...

Comment: It produces a constant when exponentiated that can be factored out of the integral.